# Print object values in toString

Tags: java

I wants to override toString() method to show name of user but Name is the inner class of User class so how can I print it.

```
public class User
{
    public static class Name 
    {
        private String _first, _last;

        public String getFirst() { return _first; }
        public String getLast() { return _last; }

        public void setFirst(String s) { _first = s; }
        public void setLast(String s) { _last = s; }
    }
    private Name _name;
    public Name getName() { return _name; }
    public void setName(Name n) { _name = n; }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "";//How to print first name and last name here
    }
}
```

Comment: Are u a .Net developer?? It is not advised in Java to use _ variables.
BTW, just return _name.getFirst()+ _name.getLast();

Comment: The fact that Name is an inner class has absolutely no bearing on how you would access the attributes of your variable _name.

Comment: @madhairsilence Its uncommon nowadays. . . but is it really not advised? It's still an alternative to this.name = name, is it not?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return _name.getFirst()+_name.getLast();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
public String toString()
{
    Name name = getName();
    return name.getFirst() + " " + name.getLast();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    String a = getName()._first;
    String b = getName()._last;
    return "a: " + a + " :: b: " + b;//How to print first name and last name here
}
```

---

```
User user = new User();
User.Name name = new User.Name();
name.setFirst("first name");
name.setLast("last name");
user.setName(name);
System.out.println(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return for example `John Deer` you can try this code:

```
@Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return _name.getFirst().concat(" ").concat(_name.getLast());
    }
```

[concat(string str)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat%28java.lang.String%29) appends the string `str` to the end of the String object it is called on. 
You can read more about it on the link.

The snippet provided above will read `First Name` from `_name`, append an empty space just after it and then append the `Last name` on the final string.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return _name.getFirst() + " " + _name.getLast();
    }
```

Call like this.

```
public class MyMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User.Name name = new Name();
        name.setFirst("Clement");
        name.setLast("Alexandria");
        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        System.out.println(user);
    }
}
```